# url jstl database

Tags: url, jstl

I am new with Java Servlets. I put a text in the database, which is a description of a course, with a clickable url. I make a connection to the database through a connection pool. It works fine. Ik use the following code (in Dutch).

```
<c:forEach items="${cursussen}" var="cursus"> //an arraylist of courses
 <tr>
   <td>
      <c:out value="${cursus.cursusNaam}" /></td> //course name
         <td><c:out value="${cursus.niveau}" /></td> //course level
         <td><c:out value="${cursus.beschrijving}" /></td> //course description with links
          </tr>
 </c:forEach>
```

The link is converted to asci characters. How can I get the original link with the aim that it remains a clickable url?

Comment: Your question is vague and confusing. I don't see any link in your code and the statement "converted to asci characters" makes no sense without seeing some concrete examples. The title does also not clearly summarize the concrete problem. Do you mean to say that you've saved HTML code in the database for some reason instead of writing HTML code in JSP file and that it is been XML-escaped by the `<c:out>` and that you thus want to disable the XML-escaping of `<c:out>`?

Comment: When I disable the the "escapeXml" attribute all the hyperlinks in the database are converted to asci characters. Example: &lt;a href=&#034;www.greenfoot.org&#034;&gt;www.greenfoot.org&lt;/a&gt;

Comment: I see. You need to revise your incorrect definition of "ASCII characters" :) Your concrete problem is that the text from the database is been XML-escaped by `<c:out>` (to prevent potential XSS attack holes) and therefore HTML appears as plain text.

Comment: You're right. From now I shall use the term XML-escape.

Answer (score 0):

If the `beschriving` contains valid HTML code, and you don't fear any XSS attack, you just need to disable the XML-escaping of the `c:out` tag:

```
<c:out value="${cursus.beschrijving}" escapeXml="false" />
```

But this is equivalent to the simpler

```
${cursus.beschrijving}
```

`<c:out>` is preciesely used to make sure all special HTML characters (`<, >, ", ', &`) are escaped. If you don't want this, no need to use the `<c:out>` tag. It has an escapeXml attribute only because in the first versions of the EL, it could only be used inside tags, and not directly in the JSP code.